# How can I parse the string representation of a decimal value to decimal (python) from a JSONField?

Tags: python, django

so I created a Model that contains a JSON field:

```
metadata = models.JSONField(verbose_name=_('Metadata'), blank=True, default=dict, db_index=True,
                            encoder=DjangoJSONEncoder, decoder=JSONDecoder(parse_float=decimal.Decimal))
```

If I access the metadata field that contains a decimal value I get a string representation of the value (that makes sense, because they are stored internally as strings. But I want that its automatically parsed to the type `decimal.Decimal`. The `json.JSONDecoder` has a parameter "parse_float", but Django wants a callable as `decoder` parameter.

I tried to pass a instantiated decoder class (but I got obviously a `ValueError`, that this must be a callable.

I also tried to start working on a subclassed `JSONDecoder`, but in the parent class I cannot see the code, what I need to adjust to receive a `decimal.Decimal`.

So I am a little bit confused how I can solve my problem. Has someone any idea?